# JSON schema: ensure a value references an array item

Tags: jsonschema

Considering the following JSON object:

```
{
    "users": [
        {"id": "user1"},
        {"id": "user2"}
    ],
    "selected": "user1"
}
```

Is there a way with JSON schema to ensure that the value of the `selected` property  is the `id` of one of the array items?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make sure object field has value existing in another field in Json Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429622/make-sure-object-field-has-value-existing-in-another-field-in-json-schema)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry. You cannot do this using JSON Schema.