# Deriving property names from values of another enum valued key in jsonschema

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

**Problem:**

The requirement to allow only those property Names in an object which are part of an array value of another property in the schema (another property's value dependant property names).

**Detailed Explanation:**

I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "validResources":["ip","domain","url"],
   "resources":
   {
      "ip" : "192.168.1.1",
      "domain" : "www.example.com",
   }
    
}
```

I would want to write a JSON schema that allows only those keys in `"resources"` which are part of the array list value of `"validResources"`.

The above JSON is a valid JSON as the `"ip"` and `"domain"` keys are actually part of the array items which is a value of the property `"validResources"`.
However, the below JSON should return an error as "file" is not a valid resource as it is not part of the `"validResorces"` array.

```json
{
  "validResources":["ip","domain","url"],
   "resources":
   {
      "ip" : "192.168.1.1",
      "file" : "file://etc/passwd" <= No such resource in "validResources"
   }

}
```

**What I have tried ?**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
              "validResources" : { "type" : "array",
                         "minItems" : 1,
                         "uniqueItems" : true
                       },
              "resources":{
                "type":"object",
              ===Unable to proceed beyond this ===
              }
               
       
    },
}
```

**Other Searches:**

I checked [propertyNames](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#property-names), however, it can derive only from another schema or have a regex pattern defined as part of its schema. But in this case, the `propertyNames` / keys within "resources" are dependent on values of the `"validResources"` property which are not known prior hand and "resources" should allow only those strings/names as its properties which are part of values in array list of `"validResources"`.

There is a pending issue somewhat similar to this question [here](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/102).

Comment: If the values you need are known before hand, then yes. If you want it to be dynamic based on data (could be any value), then no. It looks like you know all the values up front?

Comment: @Relequestual The values are not known upfront. Hence this question.

Comment: In which case, sorry, no, you cannot do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make sure object field has value existing in another field in Json Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429622/make-sure-object-field-has-value-existing-in-another-field-in-json-schema)

Comment: @Relequestual  Seems like I cant do this as on date. I am posting an explanation and marking it as an answer just for other's benefit. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @Relequestual That question does'nt answer this question directly. However the solution for both the questions is a need for a method that could access  value from instance of json schema during runtime and validate the structure accordingly which is not a feature in jsonschema as on date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a problem cannot be solved as on date with json schema where draft 7 being the latest draft while writing this post.

This question also relates to multiple issues already mentioned in github issues of json-schema spec. Apparently a proposal related to solving such issue is being tracked actively [here](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/855).

Since this deals with lookup from the value of instance of json schema and not the structural validation alone (which has been the primary motive of existence of json schema standard as on date), this probably has to be dealt differently as of now until next draft comes or the mentioned issue is taken up.

Comment: The linked issue on the JSON Schema Github... We want to enable other vocabularies to do this, and so must provide some level of guideline. The HyperSchema vocabulary DOES do this in some ways, but not in a way which is useful for your situation.